# Firestore null query returns non-nullable field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

[image]

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('foo');
var query1 = collection.where('key', isEqualTo: null);
var query2 = collection.where('key', isNotEqualTo: null);
```

Both `query1` and `query2` returns `bar` and `baz` documents.
But according to my understanding, `query1` should have returned `bar` only.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this issue. This could be something with Flutter SDK then. Javascript SDK worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlutterFire member here:

Doing `isEqualTo: null` is not supported. It is behaving as if you did `where('key')`, aka doing nothing.

As 呂學洲 mentioned, it is required to use `isNull: true`

Comment: Thanks, but can you point me to the docs where it says "isEqualTo: null" is not supported, I must have missed it.

Comment: I doubt there's docs about that. It's about how Dart and `where` works. Since Dart has no `undefined`, doing `isEqualTo:null` is identical to not passing it

Comment: Ok, that made sense. I'm accepting your answer but will award the bounty to another user as he mentioned the working solution before you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`isNull`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) instead.

```dart
query.where(key, isNull: true); //bar
query.where(key, isNull: false); //baz
```

I can't find any document describing why things implemented this way. But I'm guessing that sending `isEqualTo`/`isNotEqualTo` with null is telling Firestore to get documents that exist the field.

You can try querying document *bak* which doesn't have field `key`.

Comment: I knew `isNull` part, and it works as intended but the question was why `isEqualTo: null` also returning `"value"` documents. Even if there's no `key`, both `isEqualTo` and `isNotEqualTo` returns same documents. If no answer is provided to my exact question, then I'll accept yours (although I already knew this thing)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in `returned` data by your `queries` because

```
var query1 = collection.where('key', isEqualTo: null);
```

In `query1` basically you are running a query like -
`Select * from collection where 'key' = null and same in the query2`.

And because bar has a key that has a null value your `query1` is true and returning the data.

```
var query2 = collection.where('key', isNotEqualTo: null);
```

And same scenario is happening with above `query2` it also has a key that is not equals to `null. So it's also returning you the available data.

So because both of your `where` `conditions` are getting satisfied that's why they are `returning` you the available data.

Comment: But if you remove `key` from `bar`, then also it returns the same results.

Comment: can you add that to your question as well?

Comment: I'm sure you must have tested your code before writing the answer, so in your sample you can remove `key` and see it returning the same results.