# Cloud Firestore not showing composite index link in the console

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a query which requires creation of composite index. AFAIK, there are two ways of going around it.

1. Go to the console and manually create the index.
2. Run the query as it is to receive an error in the console which can direct me to the Firebase console after creating the index.

But I'm not seeing any such links on the console. Here's the query:

```dart
collection.where('foo', isEqualTo: 'bar').where('baz', isLessThan: 1);
```

Error:

```dart
E/flutter (21010): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(207)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
E/flutter (21010): #0      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (21010): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21010): #1      _JsonQuery.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:385:9)
E/flutter (21010): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21010): #2      _FooPageState.fooMethod (package:foo_bar_baz.dart:140:27)
E/flutter (21010): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21010): 
W/Firestore(21010): (23.0.0) [WatchStream]: (602e2ef) Stream closed with status: Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets., cause=null}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Firebase has stopped returning the index creation link in client SDKs. You can still use the Admin SDK in a Cloud Function to get direct index creation link or create one yourself manually as shown:

[image]

Make sure you replace the collection and fields names with the original names.

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68388387/13130697) and get the index creation link yourself using Functions emulator.  Meanwhile I'll try contacting Firebase if it's intentional to not show those links on client side.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they stopped creating the link on the client side.

Comment: You seem to be a member of Firebase, can you also help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68357522/12483095)?

Comment: Hey @iDecode, this is not confirmed yet (and I'm not a member of Firebase) but you can keep track on this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5152) for official confirmation.